# How to handle desktop Todo app using next js and tauri

Tags: next.js, tauri

I want to have an offline app for daily tasks to manage daily tasks, is there any offline database that I can connect with nextjs+tauri to build my app???

Since nextjs is a front-end tool, how can I solve this problem?
I really need your suggestion, thank you

Comment: SQLite or IndexedDB must be your options to look at.